# Getting 400 Error while reading JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am sending following JSON:

```
{
  "sqId": "10009",
  "pCode": [
    {
      "key": [
        [
          1,
          0,
          1
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hdId": "87",
  "sType": [
    {
      "key": [
        {
          "id": "id_1",
          "q": "1",
          "pCode": "pCode_1",
          "Type": "T_1",
          "Level": "f"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Which is mapped with below POJO:

```
public class Pinfo {

   protected String sqId;
   protected String hdId;
   protected Map<String, Integer> pCode;
   protected Map<String, List<sType>> sType;

   public Map<String, List<sType>> getsType() {
      return sType;
   }

   public void setsType(Map<String, List<sType>> sType) {
      this.sType = sType;
   }

   public String getsqId() {
      return sqId;
   }

   public void setsqId(String sqId) {
      this.sqId = sqId;
   }

   public Map<String, Integer> getpCode() {
      return pCode;
   }

   public void setpCode(Map<String, Integer> pCode) {
      this.pCode = pCode;
   }

   public String gethdId() {
      return hdId;
   }

   public void sethdId(String hdId) {
      this.hdId = hdId;
   }

}
```

Now reading the JSON using following code:

```
Map<String, Integer> pMap = (Map<String, Integer>) PinfoObj.getpCode(); //Getting Error 
logger.debug("### pMap ###"+pMap.values());
```

But I'm getting error:

> "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@5ed7c090; line: 2, column: 40] (through
>   reference chain: com.ve.pg.dto.Pinfo[\"pCode\"]); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY
>   token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5ed7c090; line: 2,
>   column: 40] (through reference chain:
>   com.vonage.pg.dto.Pinfo[\"pCode\"])"

Can't figure out what I am missing at this point, any idea or hints would be great.

Comment: Where did you get the 400 error from?

Comment: `pCode` doesn't look like a `Map<String, Integer>` to me, looks more like a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer[][]>[]>`.

Comment: Manually throwing 400 in case of Invalid Input(JSON).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error:

```
Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of
       java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
```

Is telling you "I encountered a START_ARRAY token (`[`), but you have asked me to deserialize to a map, so I was expecting to find a START_OBJECT token (`{`)"

Your mistake is to try to deserialize something like

```
[{
  "key": [
    [
      1,
      0,
      1
    ]
  ]
}]
```

to `Map<String, Integer>`, while it is actually `List<Map<String, List<List<Integer>>>>`. You should either change the structure of your `JSON`, or change the type to deserialize to.

The same mistake should be fixed for `sType`.

Comment: So if in case i have to accept <String,Integer> only what need to be changed in JSON?

Comment: {"sqId":null,"hdId":null,"pCode":{"key2":2,"key1":1},"sType":{}}

Comment: @Affy If you want to accept *only one* `integer`, the JSON should look like `{"key": 1, "value": 2, "xxx": 3}`. In your case it looks like you want to accept multiple integers (`Map<String, List<Integer>> pCode`), the corresponding JSON should look like `{"key": [1, 2, 3], "value": [4, 5, 6]}`

Answer (score 1):

Type does not match, can change like this:

```
   protected List<Map<String, List<List<Integer>>>> pCode;
   protected List<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> sType;
```